# Critical Error sound playing at seemingly random intervals for seemingly no reason

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've ran into a problem today and I'm really unsure where it originated from, the problem being that windows continues to play the Critical Error sound randomly for a reason I can't identify.

It started when I was on YouTube and I heard the sound once, so I just left it after clearing action center, however it occurred only 5 minutes later, nothing popping up in the action center so I decided to check the event viewer. In the event viewer I could find nothing that coincided with the times and so I waited, the sound continued to play at intervals anywhere from 5 to 25 minutes without warning and with nothing appearing in the event viewer. So I had to investigate.

I found someone identified which error it was by changing the wav files one by one of all the different errors sharing the sound effect (Windows Foreground.wav) and so quickly I identified that it is, in fact, a Critical Error that's being thrown.

So I turned to Stack Overflow, saw people mentioning Process Monitor, so I downloaded it and waited, finding that "taskhostw.exe" was the process that was calling the wav file, so I took note of the time the error was played and I checked to make sure that it wasn't anything in Scheduled Tasks. Nothing in there had a "Last Ran" that was close enough to the last time the error sound played for me to believe there's a Scheduled Task running.

I checked the Stack of all the "taskhostw.exe" operations related to and saw nothing but various DLL files from within System32.
[Stack from CreateFile (Left) and ReadFile (Right) when the sound last played](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtHLS.png)

[List view of all the operations performed around the sound being played.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzXE8.png)

I've also ran sfc /scannow from an elevated command prompt but it found nothing wrong that needed to be fixed.

I'm at a complete loss, I'm really confused, I've searched around and uninstalled many programs related to things people are saying caused the issue for them. I've ran numerous virus scans in the background whilst hunting down the problem. I just really could use help here.

Thanks in advance...